# Implementing SignalR cliient in Android

Tags: android, ios, signalr, signalr.client

I'm developing an Android application, which uses SignalR SDK, but I cant find good documentation about that. I have iOS code with SignalR implementation, and I try to do in android like in iOS. This is my code

```
       connection = new Connection(NEAR_SIGNALR_HOST);

        connection.getHeaders().put("NickId", String.valueOf(aNickId)); 
        connection.getHeaders().put("AuthToken", aAuthToken); 

        connection.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(JsonElement jsonElement) {
                delegate.onEvent(jsonElement.toString());
            }
        });

        connection.stateChanged(new StateChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ConnectionState connectionState, ConnectionState connectionState2) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Old state :" + connectionState);
                Log.d(TAG, "New State :" + connectionState2);
            }
        });
        connection.start();
```

After start command connection state changes from Disconnected to Connecting and then from Connecting to disconnected and I don't receive messages onMessageReceived. Have anybody some experience with it?